# How Do I Alias Alembic Provided Dependencies?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

If I evaluate the following in Emacs Cider:

```
(use 'alembic.still)

(alembic.still/distill '[enlive "1.1.5"])

(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(html)
```

... evaluation of the (html) to see if it's a recognized symbol produces an 'Unable to resolve symbol' error. I'm evaluating it via cider connected to a REPL.

How can I use Alembic provided dependencies as an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because `html` is an alias for a namespace here, not a symbol. The functions from enlive should work, however:

```
(use 'alembic.still)

(alembic.still/distill '[enlive "1.1.5"])

(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(html/html-snippet "<div>Hello world</div>")
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!